# Python sometimes does not pass class instance as first parameter - understanding __new__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

I have a class with a function like this:

```
def foo(self):
    do_stuff()
```

And I call it like this:

```
instance.foo()
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError: foo() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

but this works fine:

```
instance.foo(instance)
```

Can anyone explain why this could be happening? It's weirding me out a little

If you need more info please feel free to ask

**EDIT** here's an approximation of the actual code...

```
def __new__(self):
    blah blah
    MyClass.__init__(self,blah)
    self.foo(self)     #<------------------------error here
```

I suspect I am misunderstanding how `__new__` works... I'm doing some reading now

Comment: How do you create an instance ? `obj = classfoo()` or `obj = classfoo` ?

Comment: @AshRj: the problem is in the __new__ function. See the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass  
    def __new__(cls):
        blah
        o = object.__new__(cls)
        o.foo()
        return o
```

`__new__` needs to return an instance. It gets MyClass as an argument, not an instance of MyClass.

To instantiate `MyClass` in `__new__`, `object.__new__` is employed. This is to prevent infinite recursion

`__init__` is called automatically on the returned value of `__new__` so long as this value is of type MyClass. This can be prevented by playing with the metaclass

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the **new** function does not accept self as an argument, seeing as you're creating a new object in it. The first argument is in fact the class, usually shortened as cls.

[Source](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

Corrected sample:

```
def __new__(cls):
    blah blah
    obj = MyClass.__new__(MyClass)
    obj.foo()
    return obj
```

This will create an instance of MyClass instead of cls. If MyClass is a subclass of cls, then it's init method will also automaticly be called (see linked reference)

Comment: I thought this was correct but it isn't - your answer comes up with an infinite recursion error...

Comment: I made another answer that's correct because yours isn't quite... it was useful though so +1